# CommandLineParser ,loading image in opencv by command line arguments

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I see that in version 3 of Opencv , "CommandLineParser" is used much ;but I don't get how it works.I am new with programming.can anyone give me some help please?
another question is that , before I was working with Opencv 2 version , and reading image is quite simple by "Imread("file address",type)" but I see that in new version it is mostly done by  commandine arguments . what is advantage of this,and how it works exactly?
I am working with Visual studio 2015 on Windows 10
thanks

Comment: Here again... ;D You still load images with `imread`. CommandLineParser is just an _utility_ to interpret command line arguments, but you usually don't use it for simple tasks. So you can just read the image with `imread("path_to_file")`, `imread(argv[1])`, or whatever, as usual

Comment: thanks for response. my problem is that I don't understand how this utility "CommandLineParser" works . I need to undrestand it since in Opencv 3 it is used frequently .secondly I don't know how to use Command line arguments. and thirdly why they prefer these utilities to such a simple line (imread) ?

Comment: take a look at [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: I have seen this before,be sure I didn't write this question without ant search in google,but I don't understand it,it is understandable for professional programmers; In opencv 2 ,description are very easy and everyone can understand it,but I don't know why in OpenCv 3 everything is described in high level; if anyone can add some explanation in easy language I will be grateful. thanks